# CKeditor formatting to Facebook

Tags: wysiwyg, social-network

I'm formatting articles with Ckeditor. This works fine in Drupal 7 but when I try to share the link in Facebook the special characters appear on Facebook. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: What cleanup settings do you have activated in the CKEditor options? They could be messing with your output

Comment: CUSTOM FORMATTING OPTIONS
 Indent the element contents.
 Break line before the opening tag.
 Break line after the opening tag.

 Break line after the closing tag.

Comment: If you turn off all these settings, does the behavior persist? I'd try them one by one to ensure it isn't one of these.